# Custom Haptic Feedback for AppleWatch

Tags: notifications, apple-watch

On iOS, you can create custom vibrations for contacts whenever they call you.

Since I only recieve notifications through my Apple Watch, is it posible to change the haptic feedback patten depending on what notification you recieve or not?

I would like this so I know if the notification was from one of my social media apps, utilities or phone and SMS whithout raising my rist up to look at the notification.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not believe this is currently possible on the Apple Watch.